# Source level debugging fails due to missing ncurses library

Tags: solana-program

I'm trying to follow these [instructions](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/debugging#source-level-debugging).

Compiling the `.debug` file works. Running the program with `solana-ledger-tool program run` also works. But I got stuck at the `solana-lldb` part.

When I try to run it, I get an error about a missing library:

```
./lldb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have ncurses installed (from the official Arch Linux repos) and tried to create a symlink to mine (they are named differently). This led to the following error:

```
./lldb: /usr/lib/libpanel.so.6: version `NCURSES6_5.0.19991023' not found (required by [...]/platform-tools/llvm/bin/../lib/liblldb.so.15-rust-dev)
```

It seems that `liblldb.so.15-rust-dev` is linked against an ncurses library from 1999. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What's the platform you're running on?

Comment: Arch Linux x86_64. With up-to-date packages

Comment: I should also mention that I'm using Solana Tool Suite v1.17.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After failing to find the right libraries or to compile it on my system, I stumbled on this ([Source](https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs)):

```
We build and run on Ubuntu 20.04.
```

The Github workflow of `solana-labs/platform-tools` also states that the Linux releases are built with `os: ubuntu-20.04` (see [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/platform-tools/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml))

So, I decided to ditch my system in favor of Ubuntu 20.04. I created the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
                    wget \
                    python3-dev \
                    libxml2

RUN cd /root && \
    mkdir -p .cache/solana/v1.37/platform-tools && \
    wget "https://github.com/solana-labs/platform-tools/releases/download/v1.37/platform-tools-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2" && \
    tar jxf platform-tools-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 -C /root/.cache/solana/v1.37/platform-tools
```

Now, running `solana-lldb` inside this container works without problems!